# Change map visualization zoom level for Fusiontable

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

When I visualize a fusion table as map type, boundaries for U.S counties appear to be small red dots at zoom level 1-5, and becomes polygons since zoom level 6. Is there a way that I could get rid of red dots but showing actually polygons no matter what zoom level user chooses?

Thanks!

[fusion table which I'm using is here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=0IMZAFCwR-t7jZnVzaW9udGFibGVzOjIxMDIxNw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a limitation of FusionTables.  I made [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_world_countries.html) that uses KmlLayer for the zoom levels that don't show polygons, but it seems kind of silly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry about my such a late reply.